# Tailwind hover:scale not working with framer motion

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

For some reason I don't understand I can't make a scale effect while hovering using Tailwind when the element is wrapped in a Framer Motion animation. Can anyone help me with this? My code is below:

```
  <motion.ul
    variants={containerAnim}
    className='flex flex-col items-center'
  >
    <motion.li
      variants={childAnim}
      className='text-secondary text-[4.5rem] font-black leading-[5rem] hover:scale-110 hover:text-white duration-200'
    >
      <a href=''>About</a>
    </motion.li>
  </motion.ul>
```

When I take the motion wrapper out it works normally, but I need the motion for a start animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `!important` flag by following 2 methods  :

1. You can make any utility important by adding a `!` character to the beginning.

```
.
.
className='text-secondary text-[4.5rem] font-black leading-[5rem] hover:!scale-110 hover:!text-white !duration-200'
.
.
```

2. In the `index.css` file  , you can use `@layer` directives like this

```
@layer utilities {
  .scale-hover:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#3490dc, #6574cd) !important ;
    transform: scale(1.1) !important;
    transition-duration: 100ms !important;
    color: white !important;
  }
}
```

And  use them in component like this

```
<motion.li
      variants={childAnim}
      className='text-secondary text-[4.5rem] font-black leading-[5rem] scale-hover'
    >
      <a href=''>About</a>
    </motion.li>
```

An example you can see [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/7zDMvODunJ?file=css)

Find more resources [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important)

Comment: This worked pretty well. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I am able to help you